# I can't make Post Request (sign up ) with Flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I want to make a post request but it seems doesn't work... I don't know whats the error but when i click submit button nothing happen i don't know whether the data hasn't been post or not... Is it something wrong with my post method or anything else that may happen been error... Can somebody help me fix this or guide me the right way to make a Post request. Your help will be very appreciates.

My code

```
void registerUser() async {
    // if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
    setState(() {
      _loading = true;
    });
    String email = _emailController.text;
    String password = _passwordController.text;
    String name = _nameController.text;
    String username = _usernameController.text;
    String phone = _phoneController.text;
    String password_confirmation = _password_confirmationController.text;

    User user = await authentication.register(
        username, password, name, password_confirmation, phone, email);

    if (user != null) {
      setState(() {
        _loading = false;
      });
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyWidget()));
      // Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'Mywidget');
    }
    {
      setState(() {
        _loading = false;
      });
    }
    // }
  }
```

My button code :

```
Container(
                                  child: RaisedButton(
                                    textColor: Colors.white,
                                    color: kPrimaryColor,
                                    child: Text("S'inscrire"),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                        registerUser();
                                      }
                                      /*  Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) => MyWidget()),
                                    );*/
                                      // Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'Mywidget');
                                    },
                                    shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  width: 250,
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                )
```

authentication.dart :

```
class Authentication {
  //String token;
  Future<User> register(String name, String password_confirmation, String email,
      String phone, String password, String username) async {
    // await checkInternet();
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    };
    Map<String, String> body = {
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
      'phone': phone,
      'password': password,
      'password_confirmation': password_confirmation,
      'username': username,
    };
    inspect(body);
    inspect(headers);
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ApiUtil.AUTH_REGISTER),
        headers: headers, body: jsonEncode(body));
    inspect(response);

    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      var body = jsonDecode(response.body);
      var data = body['user'];
      User user = User.fromJson(data);
      return user;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't need to encode the body because it's already a json map.

```
var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ApiUtil.AUTH_REGISTER),
        headers: headers, body: body);
```

hint:

you can use flutter DevTools or simply print on every steps to see what's going on and which step it fails.

Comment: i deleted encode body . but i recieve this error : Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot set the body fields of a Request with content-type

Comment: wheb i print (body) ... it show me the correct value .